# Which of the actively developed Delphi components still support Kylix?

Tags: delphi, components, multiplatform, cross-kylix, kylix

I've been reading about CrossKylix recently, but for most uses one has to consider 3rd party components.
So I would like to know which of the actively developed components still support Kylix.

Many added partial or complete Kylix support back in the day, but I'm affraid some never kept updating, and the IFDEF-ed parts that compile with Kylix might not be tested.

So, ideally, I'd like a report from those with real apps and practical experience.

This might be of interest for users that are looking forward to future cross platform releases of Delphi that have been announced, as well as current Kylix/CrossKylix users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/) and [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/) still have Kylix support. At least they still have mention of Kylix all over the code.

[FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/).
[TsiLang](http://www.tsilang.com/).
[Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/features).

You can also browse [Kylix section on Torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=743). Pick category at the left menu and see if there are active projects.

Answer (score 2):

The two most known components,

- [SynEdit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/synedit/index.php?title=SynEdit_Home_Page)
- [Virtual TreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33)

both have some Kylix support.

Answer (score 1):

[TurboPower Abbrevia](http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net/) (zip/tar/gzip/bzip2) supports Kylix and CLX for everything except .cab archives, which rely on MS DLLs.